# Find the expected value of $Z=2Y_1+Y_2$ where $Y_1=\min(X_1,X_2),Y_2=\max(X_1,X_2)$ and $X_i$ is exponential with $\theta=2$

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

Where each $X_i$ is independent. I know $E(X_i)=2$. So:
$$E(Z) = E(2Y_1 + Y_2) = E[2\min(X_1,X_2) + \max(X_1,X_2)] = E\{2(X_1 or X_2) + (X_1 or X_2)\}$$

Since regardless of the outcome of the min and max functions we get the same expected values:

$$2E(X_i) + E(X_i) = 2(2) + 2 = 6$$

Only the book gives the answer as 5.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Y_1 + Y_2 = X_1 + X_2$ so 
$$E[Z] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] + E[Y_1]$$

The minimum of two independent exponential random variables with expected values $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ (and thus rates $1/\theta_1$ and $1/\theta_2$) is exponential with rate $1/\theta_1 + 1/\theta_2$ and thus expected value $\theta_1 \theta_2/(\theta_1 + \theta_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y_1+Y_2=X_1+X_2$ (why?), you get
$$
\mathbb{E} Z = \mathbb{E}[X_1+X_2+Y_1]= \mathbb{E}[X_1]+\mathbb{E}[X_2]+\mathbb{E}[Y_1] = 4 + \mathbb{E}[Y_1]
$$
so the question boils down to: "what is the expected value of the minimum of two iid exponential r.v.'s"? It is [a standard result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions) (or exercise) to show, e.g. with the cdfs, that the minimum of will also be exponential, with rate $\lambda = \frac{1}{\theta}+\frac{1}{\theta} = 1$ (i.e., $\theta^\prime= 1/\lambda =1$).

Comment: I think I need a bit more information to make sense of this. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Chris: have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-the-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another) or [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables).