# Distribution of life time of a serial circuit with bulbs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that we have a serial circuit with three bulbs. Each bulb's life time is exponentially distributed:
$$f_{bulb}(t) =\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
&\lambda e^{-\lambda t} & t \ge 0\\
&0 & t < 0
\end{aligned} 
\right.$$
Find the distribution function of the circuit's work-time (the circuit works when all three bulbs work).
\begin{align}
t &= \min \{t_1,t_2,t_3\}\\
F_{circuit}(t) &= P(T_1<t,  T_2 < t,T_3 < t)
\end{align}

I'm stuck here. Did I do this correctly? If yes how do i proceed?

(I don't know how to process the $\min\{t_1,t_2,t_3\}$ part)

Sorry if i have bad grammar or messy notation.

Comment: Hint: If you have three independent events $A$, $B$, $C$, then $P(A$ and $B$ and $C)=P(A)\cdot P(B) \cdot P(C)$.  Let $A$ be the event that $T_1<t$, let $B$ be the event that $T_2<t$, and let $C$ be the event that $T_3<t$.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the part that bugging me, i edited the problem to be more specific.

Comment: This is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-the-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another

Comment: @saulspatz That was extremely helpful. Thank you.