# The amount of time using exponential distribution?

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

I have no idea how to approach this kind of questions...

There is train A which arrives according to an Exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, and train B which arrives according to an Exponential distribution with parameter $\mu$.

1. Solve for the distribution of T, the amount of time a person will wait before either A or B arrives.
2. John wanted to take train A to go to the party, but he realized that he would arrive too early. So he decides that he will wait for the second arrival of train A. Find the distribution of
   Z = $X_1 + X_2$, the amount of time that John will wait to take the train.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The time waiting before *either* A or B arrives is the **minimum** of the two waiting times for each train. If $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are exponentially distributed, then $T = \min\{X_{1},X_{2}\}$ is also exponentially distributed. 
   If you get stuck on showing this, check out this link [How to Prove that the minimum of two exponential random variables is another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580279/414731)
2. The distribution of the sum of exponentials can be found using convolutions
   $$f_{Z}(z) = \int_{0}^{z}f_{X_{1}}(s)f_{X_{2}}(z-s)ds$$
   Then plug in the density function for the exponential and evaluate the integral. (I am not sure whether you are defining parameter $\lambda$ as $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ or $f(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}$

Comment: Aah thank you so much !!