# The expected value of the minimum of two random variables conditional on the smaller random variable.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with rate $\lambda$. Let $Y$ be a generic continuous random variable, which is independet of $X$. Define random variable $Z = \min\{X,Y\}$. I am interested in $E[Z|Z = X]$ and $E[Z|Z = Y]$.

I think, if $Y$ is an exponential distribution with rate $\mu$, then the two expected values are equal to $1/(\lambda + \mu)$---I could not show it though. However, I do not think the equality holds if $Y$ is not exponential. I would appreciate if someone could help me derive the two expected values for the generic continuous $Y$.

Comment: A proof of what you tried to show can be found at [How to Prove that the minimum of two exponential random variables is another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-the-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another)

Comment: @WaveX Thanks, but my question is different in the sense that I am interested in the expected value of the minimum, GIVEN that X<Y.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Suppose that $Y$ is an exponential distribution with rate $\mu$.
Note that for $z>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(Z>z|Z=X)&=P(Z>z|X\leq Y)=\frac{P(Z>z,X\leq Y)}{P(X\leq Y)}\\&=\frac{P(z<X\leq Y)}{P(X\leq Y)}\\&=\frac{\int_z^\infty\int_x^\infty\lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}\,dy\,dx}{\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}\,dy\,dx}\\&=e^{-(\lambda+\mu)z}=P(X>z,Y>z)\\&=P(Z>z).
\end{align*}
So $Z$ and $\{Z=X\}$ are independent, hence
$$E[Z|Z=X]=E[Z]=\frac1{\lambda+\mu}.$$
For the same reason, 
$$E[Z|Z=Y]=E[Z]=\frac1{\lambda+\mu}.$$

Comment: Thanks, @Feng Shao It might help me find my answer for the second part of my question as well. Just one note: I think, you need to change the order of integration in your integrals. Imean, dydx, instead of dxdy.

Comment: @Amir Fixed now. Some ideas:$E[Z|Z=X]=E[Z|Z=Y] \iff  EZ=E[Z|Z=X]P(Z=X)+E[Z|Z=Y]P(Z=Y)=E[Z|Z=X](P(Z=X)+P(Z=Y))=E[Z|Z=X]$ so you just need to find $Y$ such that $EZ=E[Z|Z=X]$.

Comment: please note that my question is not about finding $Y$, such that $E[Z|Z=X]$ and $E[Z|Z=Y]$ are equal. My question is about finding a closed-form solution for these two expected values when $Y$ is a generic continuous random variable. Re. your comment: you can factor out $E[Z|Z=X]$, only if $E[Z|Z=X] = E[Z|Z=Y]$, which we do not know if it holds for a generic $Y$---in your proof above, you showed it only when $Y$ is exponential.