# Compute Cov$(A, A \wedge B)$

Tags: random-variables, covariance

Assume that A and B are independente exponentially distributed random variables with rates $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Compute $Cov(A,A\wedge B)$

My incomplete solution is:
$$
Cov(A,A\wedge B) = E(A(A \wedge B)) - E(A)E(A \wedge B)
$$
From that:
$$
E(A(A\wedge B) = E(A(A\wedge B)| A <B)*\mathcal{P}(A<B) + E(A(A\wedge B)| B<A)*\mathcal{P}(B<A)
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{P}(A<B) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}; \mathcal{P}(B<A) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}
$$

From that I don't know how to keep going. The solution assess(1):
$$
E(A(A\wedge B)| A <B) = E((A \wedge B)^2) = \frac{2}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}
$$
and (2):
$$
E(A(A\wedge B)| B<A) = E[(B+A')B] = E((A \wedge B)^2) + E[B]E[A'] = \frac{2}{(\alpha+\beta)^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha+\beta)}
$$

Could someone explain me why 1 and 2?

Comment: By $A \wedge B$ do you mean $\max(A,B)$ ?

Comment: no, I mean the "min"

Comment: You min the mean ?

Comment: No, for me $\wedge$ is the MINIMUM between A and B.

Comment: Don't pay attention to my last comment, it was a pun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using a few special properties of the exponential distribution.

> **Claim 1.** If $A$ and $B$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then, conditioned on $A < B$, the random variables $U := A \land B$ and $V := (A \lor B) - (A \land B)$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\alpha + \beta$ and $\beta$ respectively. (Similarly if conditioning on $B < A$ instead, the parameters would be $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha$ instead.)

The next claim is a corollary of the first. It is not necessary for solving your question but it is somewhat relevant given the author's rather casual tendency to drop the conditioning.

> **Claim 2.** Consequently, the distribution of $U := A \land B$ (not conditioned on any event) is also exponential with parameter $\alpha + \beta$.

If we assume these claims, the (1) and (2) follow easily.

For (1): $E[A(A \land B) \mid A < B] = E[(A \land B)^2 \mid A < B]$ is direct. Then $E[(A \land B)^2 \mid A < B] = E[(A \land B)^2]$ follows from Claim 2. Finally, note that the second moment of an $\text{Exponential}(\alpha + \beta)$ distribution is $2/(\alpha + \beta)^2$.

(Actually, the step $E[(A \land B)^2 \mid A < B] = E[(A \land B)^2]$ is not really necessary, since by Claim 1 you already know that $A \land B$ conditioned on $A < B$ is exponential with parameter $\alpha + \beta$, but maybe the author had a different thought process.)

For (2): $A'$ is presumably defined as $V := (A \lor B) - (A \land B)$ (which is equivalent to $A-B$ when conditioned on $B < A$). So,
\begin{align}
&E[A(A\land B) \mid B<A]
\\
&=E[(U+V)U \mid B < A]
\\
&= E[U^2 \mid B < A] + E[VU \mid B < A]
\\
&= E[U^2 \mid B< A] + E[V \mid B<A] E[U\mid B,A]
& \text{$U$ and $V$ are cond. indep. given $B <A$}
\\
&= \frac{2}{(\alpha + \beta)^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta}.
\end{align}

Frankly I think the author's steps are a little misleading, but maybe I am missing a simpler way of approaching this.

---

Proof of Claim 1.

Let $U=A\land B$ and $V= A \lor B - A \land B$.
We have
\begin{align}
P(U > u, V > v, A < B)
&= P(A > u, B-A > v)
\\
&= \int_u^\infty \int_{a+v}^\infty f_A(a) f_B(b) \, db \, da
\\
&= \int_u^\infty \alpha e^{-\alpha a} \int_{a+v}^\infty \beta e^{-\beta b} \, db \, da
\\
&= e^{-\beta v} \int_u^\infty \alpha e^{-(\alpha + \beta) a} \, da
\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} e^{-(\alpha + \beta)u} e^{-\beta v}.
\end{align}
Consequently, since you know that $P(A<B)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$,
$$P(U>u, V>v \mid A < B) = e^{-(\alpha + \beta)u} e^{-\beta v}$$
which shows that, conditioned on $A < B$, the random variables $U$ and $V$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\alpha + \beta$ and $\beta$ respectively.

The proof when conditioning on $B<A$ is very similar.

For Claim 2, just note that
$$P(U > u) = P(U>u \mid A < B) P(A<B) + P(U>u \mid B<A)P(B<A)
= e^{-(\alpha + \beta)u} (P(A<B)+P(B<A))
= e^{-(\alpha + \beta)u}.$$

---

Alternatively, note that you can brute force compute these expressions directly without knowing about Claims 1 and 2.

\begin{align}
E[A(A\land B) \mathbf{1}_{A < B}]
&= \int_0^\infty \int_a^\infty a^2 f_A(a) f_B(b) \, db \, da
\\
&= \int_0^\infty a^2 \alpha e^{-\alpha a}\int_a^\infty \beta e^{-\beta b} \, db \, da
\\
&= \int_0^\infty a^2 \alpha e^{-(\alpha + \beta) a}
\\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} \frac{2}{(\alpha+ \beta)^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
E[A(A\land B) \mathbf{1}_{B < A}]
&= \int_0^\infty \int_b^\infty ab f_A(a) f_B(b) \, da \, db
\\
&= \int_0^\infty b\beta e^{-\beta b} \int_b^\infty a \alpha e^{-\alpha a} \, da \, db
\\
&\overset{*}{=} \int_0^\infty b\beta e^{-\beta b} \frac{1}{\alpha} (\alpha b + 1) e^{-\alpha b} \, db
\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha(\alpha + \beta)} \int_0^\infty (\alpha b^2 + b) (\alpha + \beta) e^{-(\alpha + \beta)b} \, db
\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha (\alpha + \beta)} \left(\frac{2\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta)^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta}\right)
\\
&= \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \left(\frac{2}{(\alpha + \beta)^2} + \frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha + \beta)} \right)
\end{align}

where the starred equality is from integration by parts:
$\int_b^\infty a \alpha e^{-\alpha a} \, da = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{\alpha b}^\infty u e^{-u} \, du = \frac{1}{\alpha} e^{-\alpha b} (\alpha b+1)$.

Comment: That's impressive and really clear. May I ask you from where did you get the claims? Have you read them on a book or whatever?

Comment: On the proof of (2) I didn't get how you solved $E(V^2|B<A)$

Comment: Sorry, I fixed some typos, it should make more sense now. @Gabriele

Comment: @Gabriele Claim 2 is easy to prove on its own and is very common in textboks, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another-exponen). Unfortunately, the steps for equation (2) require something stronger than Claim 2, so I wrote down Claim 1 and proved it to illuminate your author's steps. I think Claim 1 can be framed in the context of superposition of Poisson processes, which might be a more common way of introducing these concepts, but I didn't want to assume you knew about Poisson processes.