# Mixing Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a question regarding how we mix probabilities, let's say I have a device that is made of two components in series and it needs both components to work. The duration of both components is modelled by an exponential distribution with two different means, $m$ and $n$. The two durations of the components are independent. What will be the distribution of the duration of the whole device? How do I mix the information of these two components together?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, you want the [distribution of the minimum of two exponential distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another-exponen)

Comment: Yes thank you, I hadn't seen that page when looking for an answer